# Superlatives with the prefix наи

Tags: одним-словом

When can I use superlatives like  ***наи***лучший  instead of the word *самый*?

If I had to guess I'd say that the former is slightly more bookish but I'm not really sure.
Usually I'd just use something like *самый лучший*. So the question is: which variant is more commonly used in everyday speech?

Comment: Thanks! It is advisable, though, to wait for 24 hours before accepting an answer so that other people have their chance at giving a better answer.

Comment: besides **самый** there's also **наиболее**, it's a softer superlative operator, also bookish, but just as superlatives with the prefix **наи-** is used in educated speech

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `"наи-"` adjectives are indeed poetic or bookish. `"Самый ..."` is not only more broadly used, it's virtually always the safe choice.

This prefix can be used with adjectives that are in superlative form and can be applied to a human `"наилучший"`/"the best" , `"наимудрейший"`/"the most wise". Adjectives that normally can't be applied to a human (like `"наимягчайший"`/"the softest", `"наисложнейший"`/"the most difficult") are seeing even more rare use, and I wouldn't advise a non-fluent speaker to ever use those.